# Can not customize ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm study documentation on developer.android.com, and at lesson **"Styling the Action Bar"**, I have a problem. I need **change background** of ActionBar, as [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground). I generated all images(for background, buttons, etc.) using [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=be000f%2C100&secondaryColor=ddc7c7%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=ffaeae%2C100&cabBackColor=e6bebe%2C100&cabHighlightColor=e0b195%2C100), and added result to res/ dir of my project. 

It looks like this: 
[image]

I added file res/values/themes.xml manually, because it didn't exist after creating project.
Here is the code of res/values/themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>-->

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And to apply this theme, I added

> android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"

for application, and for 2 activities in AndroidManifest.xml. Here is the code of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mysecondapp.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mysecondapp.app.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.mysecondapp.app.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.mysecondapp.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

But, in result background not changes.
Preview:

[image]

If I run this app on emulator, nothing happens too.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this

Worked fine for me

```
 <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>


<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try out this code:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); // or MainActivity.getInstance().getActionBar()
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("YOUR COLOR"));
```

No Need to use the styling of the Action Bar. This is the simplest one you can ever do.

Comment: Thank you for comment, but as I say, i'm study, and I want to understand why my example from offcial android documentation not work, because I did everything as it is written in docs.